# Calculating probabilities with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the accident probabilities given airplane type. For the simplicity; assume that I have the following dataframe

```
Airplane Accident
A           1    
A           1
A           1
A           0
B           1
B           0
B           0
C           1
C           0
```

and what I want to get is first getting the individual accident probabilities for each airplane type:

```
Airplane   prob
A          0.75
B          0.33
C          0.5
```

And finally wanna get the maximum value in dataframe which corresponds to 0.75. How to do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df.groupby('Airplane')['Accident'].mean()
```

Output:

```
Airplane
A    0.750000
B    0.333333
C    0.500000
```

Then to get max:

```
df.groupby('Airplane')['Accident'].mean().max()
```

Output:

```
0.75
```